# Hit a route in laravel 5 application using pre request scripts in postman?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postman

So I am using postman to test my API endpoints. I test CRUD for all the resources. But every time I run the tests, the database state changes and which is why the next iteration of tests fail for obvious reasons.

I can see that there are pre request scripts section where I can define scripts to run before execution in postman. Now to come around the database state change issue, I usually reseed the database via the command line using artisan which comes with laravel. I can do the same by code in the application.

My point is that I can define a route which can reseed the database and I can hit that route in the pre request of the first API end point which is authentication. This way every iteration will have the same database state.

So I am trying this in the pre request script of the first endpoint:

```
$.get('http://{{host}}/api/reseed', function(response){
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("foo", response);
});
```

Since I don't have any other way for feedback, I am trying to see the response by saving it in an environment variable. But this doesn't seem to work maybe because it is an async request or maybe some other reason. I don't see the environment variable set.

Does anyone know a better way to do this? Or a solution to the one I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/697

According to this, the feature is not available yet. So I worked with a turnaround.

I simply created a request named AAA-reset so that it ends up first in the order. I guess there is another way to tweak the order internally in the postman collection but I just hacked it up.

This request runs before an other and hits a simple route in my application which resets the database.

I used the `-r` flag in `newman` to set the request time to a bigger value since seeding takes time.

I also set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` in my route in laravel to avoid hitting the execution time roof with PHP either.